# Google Maps Custom Image and custom coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google API to build a map for a game. The problem is that I am trying to use lat/long to show the coordinates and I'm trying to match these coordinates to the map coordinates which start at the top left corner.

Link: http://cstauffer.com/dayz/map/ARMAII_MAP.html

I have looked around but I have not found many documents or help with modifying the math behind the lat/long. Now this map is just a 2D map, so I don't need Mercator projections, just x/y and zoom level. Any tips/help would be appreciated.

Some information I should add: 8,960 x 8,960 image. I want the top left to start at 0,0. This is a flat map and the zoom levels used are 2-6.

Comment: Just a heads-up, it appears that you are trying to load the Google Maps JavaScript twice and your first JavaScript URL appears to contain your key, which you don't want to place in the clear. You shouldn't have to provide a key just to load the more recent versions of Google Maps JavaScript. I assume you have a license and you should be using a [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/guide#Signup) when you load the API, not the key. Since your key has now been exposed, you are probably going to want to generate a new key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you may be looking for these:

- `google.maps.Map.getProjection`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)
- `google.maps.Projection.fromLatLngToPoint`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection)

Comment: I have tried playing with those items, but I have been unable to get the coordinates to start from the top left.  My coordinates are default 0,0 at the center of my map atm.

Comment: I don't think I have enough info to give you much more help. Your JavaScript class, `GMICMapType`, looks fairly complex and I just don't have time to dig through the details. One thing that is confusing is that you say in your question that you want the the top left to be `0,0` but in your comment above you say that `0,0` is at the center. I'm sure that makes sense, but it seems to say 2 different things. Maybe if you include more detail in your question, along with the code that applies to your question, it may allow me or others to give you more guidance.